# How can I monitor status changes of windows services under windows xp?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-services, windows-xp

I'm trying to write a program in C, that can detect when some Windows services (aka. NT services) are started or stopped.

There seems to be a function [NotifyServiceStatusChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684276(VS.85).aspx), but that's only available on Vista and Windows 7. I'm trying to do this on Win XP, so what's the best way? Is there any other than continuous polling?

edit:

Is anybody able to give answer in C? I'm also ok with C++, but I'd like to stay away from scripting.

Comment: Since this isn't a qualified answer I am adding it as a comment: the closest you can get is `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` watching the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services` key for machine-local services

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the closest you can get in XP is [QueryServiceStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684941%28VS.85%29.aspx) (single service) or [EnumServicesStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682640%28VS.85%29.aspx) (multiple services).

To avoid repeatedly calling either of these, some recommend a WMI setup, querying `Win32_Service`'s `state` property.  See the bottom of [this thread](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-286820.html) for more details.

The following is a (basic) WMI script to monitor the alerter service's status:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:" &_
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!" &_
    "\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set objEventSource = objSWbemServices.ExecNotificationQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent " &_
    "WITHIN 10 " &_
    "WHERE TargetInstance " &_
    "ISA 'Win32_Service' " &_
    "AND TargetInstance.Name = 'alerter'")

Set objEventObject = objEventSource.NextEvent()
Wscript.Echo "The status of the alerter service just changed."
```

The above, and additional examples, may be found on [this TechNet page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wmi_kzcp.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do it by polling.  Place the code in a separate thread and send it to sleep for as long as reasonable. Say every second, perhaps even 5 seconds to minimize system performance.

As a 'c' example for a single service:

//  various handles and strings plus...
    SERVICE_STATUS  ssStatus;
    ...

```
    schSCManager = OpenSCManager( ServiceComputerNameStr,
                                  NULL,
                                  SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS );
    if ( schSCManager == NULL )
        {
//        ...  error stuff  
        goto cleanup;
        }

    scphService = OpenService( schSCManager,
                               ServiceNameStr,
//                               SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS );
                               SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS );
    if ( scphService == NULL )
        {
//        ... error stuff  
        goto cleanup;
        }

    if ( !QueryServiceStatus(scphService, ssStatus) )
        {
//        ... error stuff  
        goto cleanup;
        }
```

The result you want will be in the ssStatus.dwCurrentState.

Comment: There are some other options except polling, such as WMI

Comment: @Thomasek WMI is still polling the services.  The original poster asked for an XP solution, and as he pointed out NotifyServiceStatusChange is *not* available in XP.  Polling is far from ideal.  But if there is an *XP* way of reading service state without it (at some level) I'd be very interested to know.