# Detect/listen for service start and stop state changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, event-handling

I have a C# application that uses a Windows service that is not always on and I want to be able to send an email notification when the service starts and when it shuts down. I have the email script written, but I cannot seem to figure out how to detect the service status changes.

<strike>I have been reading up on the `ServiceController` class and I think that the `WaitForStatus()` method might be what I need, but I haven't been able to find an example with it being used on a service that is not yet started.</strike> EDIT: Due to the fact that the `WaitForStatus()` method busy-waits and I need to be executing the rest of the program run by the service while listening for the service to start/stop, I don't think that this is the method for me, unless someone has a solution that uses this method combined with multithreading and is clean and efficient.

More:

- the service will not be started by the application - the application user will be starting that directly from the Services window in the Administrative Tools.
- the service used is not a default Windows service - it is a custom service designed for use with this application

Thanks for your help!

P.S. please note that I'm fairly new to C# and am learning as I go here.

UPDATE:

I have managed to get the alert email to send each time the service starts: As I continued to read through the code that I have (which I, unfortunately, cannot post here), I noticed that the class used to create the service was extending the `ServiceBase` class and that someone made a custom `OnStart()` method to override the default one. I added the necessary method calls to the new `OnStart()` method and it successfully sent the notifications.

I attempted to do the same thing for the `OnStop()` method, but that did not work out so well for me - before I continue, I would like to add that I have been programming in Java for several years, and I am very familiar with Java design patterns.

What I attempted to do, which would have worked in Java, was override the `ServiceBase` class's `OnStop()` method with one that calls the email notification, cast `MyService` to be of type `ServiceBase` and then re-call the `ServiceBase` class's `Stop()` method (NOTE: `OnStop()` is a protected method so it could not be called directly - the `Stop()` method calls `OnStop()` and then continues with the necessary code to stop the service). I thought that casting to type `ServiceBase` would force the default `OnStop()` method to be called, instead of my custom one.

As you may imagine, I ended up with just under 10,000 emails successfully sent to my inbox before I managed to force my computer into a hard shutdown.

What I need now is a way to either use my overridden `OnStop()` method and then have it call the default method, or another solution to this problem. Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks so much.

FOR THOSE OF YOU WITH MULTITHREADING SOLUTIONS:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
     string subject = "Notice: Service Started";
     string body = "This message is to notify you that the service " +
         "has been started. This message was generated automatically.";
     EmailNotification em = new EmailNotification(subject, body);
     em.SendNotification();

     ...INITIALIZE LISTENER FOR SERVICE STOPPING HERE...

     ...custom stuff to be run on start...
 }
```

Also, remember that the class that this method is called in, let's call it `Service`, extends the `ServiceBase` class.

UPDATE TWO:

In regards the suggestion that I use `NotifyServerStatusChange` I have learned that it is not permitted for the solution to use system functions, due to various reasons. To clarify, only solutions that are purely within the scope of C# and .NET are viable. Thanks, again, for your help!

Comment: right, but the application is not checking for the status on an event - it needs to be continually listening for the status change

Comment: @Chriseyre2000: This is a valid solution and, so far, the only one that I have. If you want to delete the comment and make it an answer I will vote it up, as it is the ONLY answer to this on SO. However, as the article itself says, the code will wind up being messy and I really cant go in that direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I respond to a change in status for a Windows Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743836/how-can-i-respond-to-a-change-in-status-for-a-windows-service)

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: both the question that you said this was a repeat from and the question that it linked to had answers that applied to C++ NOT C#. If you cared to look at the documentation that those questions referenced you would have seen that even in the Microsoft documentation only the C++ code was shown or referenced. I have looked up notifyservicestatuschange and have yet to find a single example anywhere that uses that method in C#. Now, if this function does work in C#, feel free to post it as an answer and if it works I will upgrade and accept it.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel You have access to all Win32 functions in C# via PInvoke, anything that is Win32 C++ *can be* C# if you care do put the effort into it.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: also, Peter, in the future I would ask that you review the answers in the "possible original question" that you are referring to in order to make sure that they are actually correct and on point before insinuating that the person who asked the question did not do their homework. This question has had 43 unique views and two answers, one of which refers to documentation that flat out calls the solution "messy". I would hazard to say that this is a question that has yet to be asked on SO.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: as I said, I am new to C# and have been doing all the research that I can. However, C# is not a language that can be learned in a single day, and I did not yet learn that I had access to all Win32 functions in C#. Please feel free to post your solution as an answer and I will gladly accept and upgrade it.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Unfortunately, I was just told that I must stay within the scope of C# and .NET for this solution. Apparently our client believes that there are security issues associated with using system functions and specified at the beginning of the project that we must avoid using them. If you choose to post this as an answer, however, I will still upgrade it as it is a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution and why I could not find it before: As I said earlier, my class extended the ServiceBase class. In my first update, I posted that I attempted to solve this in the same way I would have solved it with Java: through casting. However, in C# casting apparently doesn't let you call the base method if you overrode it in the derived class. One of the things that I did not know when I first posted this question and this update (and clearly one of the things that no one thought of) was that C# includes the `base` constructor that can be used to call methods of the base class from a derived class. As the `base` constructor can be used for any class in C# it does not appear in the [ServiceBase Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.aspx).

Once I learned this, I was able to take my original solution and modify it to use the base class:

```
    protected override void OnStop() {
        string subject = "Notice: Service Stopped";
        string body = "This message is to notify you that the service has " +
            "been stopped. This message was generated automatically.";
        EmailNotification em = new EmailNotification(subject, body);
        em.SendNotification();
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

I figured this out when I was playing around with the code in Visual Studio and noticed `base` in my IntelliSense. I clicked to go to its definition and it sent me to ServiceBase (where it was obviously not defined). After noticing that base was not defined in my code and that it was an instance of the ServiceBase class I realized that it must have been some sort of constructor. After a quick Google search, I found what I was looking for. Way to go IntelliSense!

Thank you everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a .NET solution with no win32 api then check out my solution below. I'm inheriting from the ServiceController class and using the WaitForStatus() inside of a Task to make it non-blocking then raising events when the status changes. Perhaps it needs more testing but works for me:

**CLASS DEFINITION**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess; // not referenced by default

public class ExtendedServiceController: ServiceController
{
    public event EventHandler<ServiceStatusEventArgs> StatusChanged;
    private Dictionary<ServiceControllerStatus, Task> _tasks = new Dictionary<ServiceControllerStatus, Task>();

    new public ServiceControllerStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            base.Refresh();
            return base.Status;
        }
    }

    public ExtendedServiceController(string ServiceName): base(ServiceName)
    {
        foreach (ServiceControllerStatus status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceControllerStatus)))
        {
            _tasks.Add(status, null);
        }
        StartListening();
    }

    private void StartListening()
    {
        foreach (ServiceControllerStatus status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceControllerStatus)))
        {
            if (this.Status != status && (_tasks[status] == null || _tasks[status].IsCompleted))
            {
                _tasks[status] = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        base.WaitForStatus(status);
                        OnStatusChanged(new ServiceStatusEventArgs(status));
                        StartListening();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // You can either raise another event here with the exception or ignore it since it most likely means the service was uninstalled/lost communication
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnStatusChanged(ServiceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<ServiceStatusEventArgs> handler = StatusChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class ServiceStatusEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ServiceControllerStatus Status { get; private set; }
    public ServiceStatusEventArgs(ServiceControllerStatus Status)
    {
        this.Status = Status;
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExtendedServiceController xServiceController = new ExtendedServiceController("myService");
    xServiceController.StatusChanged += xServiceController_StatusChanged;
    Console.Read();

    // Added bonus since the class inherits from ServiceController, you can use it to control the service as well.
}

// This event handler will catch service status changes externally as well
private static void xServiceController_StatusChanged(object sender, ServiceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Status Changed: " + e.Status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class has a `WaitForStatus` method. Internally it does polling, though.

Comment: Yeah, the polling aspect makes it a no-go unless someone can show me how I can create a new thread for this job without it costing me much in the way of performance (Note: I have been looking into multi-threading this application, but, as I said before, I am a bit new to C# and from what I've read it doesn't sound like it will work properly or efficiently - thoughts?)

Comment: Do you think that one or a few polling threads are a performance problem? They wake up every 250ms. Why would you think this is a no-go?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was very clear in my comment - I didn't mean that the polling would be a performance concern, only having a second thread. Polling itself would be totally fine with me in terms of performance, but I need to be doing things while the program is listening for the service to stop. By definition, polling is busy-waiting, which I cannot do unless I have two threads so that I can busy-wait in one and go through the rest of the program in the other.

Comment: Ok, can't you just create a second thread? Maybe I don't fully understand your situation but I cannot see a reason why a new thread would be a problem. Neither performance-wise nor regarding anything else. You can reduce the stack size of that thread if you care about memory usage. The Thread ctor takes a threadSize argument.

Comment: That would be great, then. As I said, I have been reading up on multithreading and creating more threads, but I am still unclear as to how I should go about creating and deleting the thread in this situation. In a few moments, I will add an edit to the question and will show you where I would (or at least where I think I would) create the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wmi to monitor for events: [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730927.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730927.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't PInvoke NotifyServiceStatusChange, then you'll have to poll the service.  For example:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Some Service");
Console.WriteLine("Status = " + sc.Status);
```

Comment: This is a good solution that would work great if we were to implement a "heartbeat monitor", however our specifications require that the solution be a part of the service itself, which executes when the service is told to stop, just before it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Be very carefull with the use of NotifyServiceStatusChange(), because it is only supported on Windows Vista/Windows 2008 (and above). If you target any platforms below, you can't use that API. (There are still lots of XP/Windows 2000-2003 systems out there.)

To make it even worse, polling will not be always reliable in case of service restarts, because if you are polling a service on a very fast system (SSD-drives or pre-buffered I/O on virtual machines), the service might restart between two polls.

Comment: Thanks - I regularly check stack and always review new answers/comments on my posts/questions that I have posted on. Your post is very insightful, but it is more of a comment than a solution - do you have an alternative solution to suggest, as well? (If not, please change your post to be a comment and not an answer) Thanks :)